# Error: invalid operands of types 'float' and 'float' to binary 'operator%'

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I just started to program in C and I found a problem when running the program.
The error is the following,`resto == a % b`;

> [Error] invalid operands of types 'float' and 'float' to binary 'operator%' in C

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

char n;

int main (){

    printf ("Programma che svolge ogni tipo di operazione aritmetica tra 2 numeri a e b\n'n' per chiudere\nPremere 'invio' per continuare\n");
    float a, b, somma, differenza, prodotto, quoziente;
    int resto;
    while (n=getchar()!='n'){
        printf ("Inserisci a\n");
        scanf ("%f",&a);

        printf ("Inserisci b\n");
        scanf ("%f",&b);

        somma = a + b;
        differenza = a - b;
        prodotto = a * b;
        quoziente = a / b;
        resto = a % b;

        printf ("somma = %f + %f = %f\n",a,b,somma);
        printf ("differenza = %f - %f = %f\n",a,b,differenza);
        printf ("prodotto = %f * %f = %f\n",a,b,prodotto);
        printf ("quoziente = %f / %f = %f\n",a,b,quoziente);
        printf ("resto = %f %% %f = %d\n",a,b,resto);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The solution there:

[image: postimg.org/image/guoxt6evn]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The error is the following,' resto == a % b' ;

That's because the modulus operator `%` cannot apply to `float` or `double`. It's meant to get the **remainder** when integer type `x` is divided by `y`. It does not have any meaning when you use it with `float` or `double`.

Also spotted by Draco18s, this `resto == a % b` is not what you want even if `a` and `b` are integer type. The `==` is logical operator, so that expression will yield a temporary value of `1` (for true) and `0` otherwise. But that temporary value is *NOT* assigned to `resto` at all. You need to use assignment operator `=` instead.

Comment: You have to change the type of `a` and `b` to integer, not the result type.

Comment: You're saying correctly .
My problem is something else , however :
If I wanted to put a number with a comma and in a and a number with a comma and b , as I should do?
What you said is fine if a and b are integers ! Should I apply if? @Draco18s

Comment: Now just spotted another issue with your code. When you change `a` and `b` to `int`; you must change the control string in `scanf` and `printf` accordingly, ie `%d` instead of `%f`.

Comment: The value `1,2367` (or `1.2367` in other locals) is not an integer and the modulo operator *is not defined* for floating point numbers.  If you want to use floats, use `fmod`

Comment: Not having programmed in C myself in over 10 years, Google it.

Comment: @Draco18s
I LOVE YOU <3
http://postimg.org/image/guoxt6evn/

works well , thank you so much !!!

Comment: Mathematically, the "remainder" operation is well-defined for non-integers.  In fact `fmod` does that. It's just the C `%` operator which is defined to only work on integers (probably for "historical reasons")

Answer (score 1):

Following comment discussion, the problem boils down to this line:

```
    float a, b, somma, differenza, prodotto, quoziente;
    int resto;
```

You need to change `a` and `b` to integers:

```
    float somma, differenza, prodotto, quoziente;
    int a, b, resto;
```

Due to the issue pointed out by @artm

Comment: The comparison error is well spot, but the compiler error is because `a` and `b` are float, so he cannot apply `%` operator.

Comment: Ah ha, I apologize.  Next time use comments to indicate the relevant line.  e.g. `resto = a % b; // ERROR HERE`

Comment: I'm new and I have yet to understand how to change a question .

Comment: Thanks so much! @Draco18s

Comment: So my question after that is was c++ created with a way to perfom the same function as a modulus to floats in any way? I am trying to make a logic check to see if user input is better classified as a float or an int.

Comment: @TylerLazenby Have you tried searching? No really, type "c++ modulo float" into Google.

Comment: @Draco18s I did but I got all sorts of confused. I am still learning C++ though so that probably has  lot to do with it.

Comment: @TylerLazenby https://s3.postimg.org/f91kbm2ir/floatmod.png the first result is the same link posted in ori0n's answer, the third link is a SO question, the second link is a forum post asking your question and has the answer as a reply, referring again to `fmod`. I don't know how you could be getting confused.

Comment: Because I can be dumb like that, and no that isn't sarcasm. That is genuine admittance of stupidity sometimes. But thank you so much for pointing that out.